# Toolbar style doesn't work

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-styles

I'm trying to make a light-blue toolbar with white text color:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        style="@style/ToolbarStyle"/>
```

and in my styles.xml:

```
<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

But there's one problem, the text color is black instead of white

**Note:** Using `android:theme` or `app:theme` instead of `style` will fix the problem, but I still wanna know, why doesn't `style` work?

Comment: Did you use setSupprtActionBar(mToolBar) in your activity?

Comment: @KrupalShah Yes, I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the problem now,

`style` is used to style a view without its children views.
`android:theme` and `app:theme` are used to style the view and its children.

So when it comes to styling the toolbar, you will probably want to style it and its children views so the activity label will be styled as well.

Comment: Great can you provide an example to make this answer more complete?